# Laravel package controller alias in routes

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5, service-provider

I'm trying to create package in Laravel 5.2 with routes. I have controller in `Http/Controllers` folder (with namespace `vendor\package\Http\Controllers\MyController`). I want to create alias but I don't know how. I don't want to call this controller in `routes.php` like that:

```
Route::get('myurl', vendor\package\Http\Controllers\MyController::class . '@action');
```

But like that:

```
Route::get('myurl', 'MyController@action');
```

I tried to search this in `Application` class API but I can't find this information.

This code in package provider doesn't work.

```
$this->app
     ->alias(vendor\package\Http\Controllers\MyController::class, 'MyController');
```

My service provider:

```
class PackageRouterServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        include(__DIR__ . '/../Http/routes.php');

        $this->app->alias(MyController::class, 'MyController'); // <- I tried this
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get your package controller in your application routes.php file, not in a package routes file? This doesn't make much sense for me. If you want to create dynamic URL's for your package controller actions I think that you need to find another way to do it, for example with a package config file.

Comment: @GerardReches No no no, it's my package routes file.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that your routes can't find the controller without its full namespace? Can you show your package RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: @GerardReches Okay I edited my question. And yes - Laravel says 'class not found' when I write class name without full namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your `PackageRouterServiceProvider.php` like this:

```
class PackageRouterServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // Set this namespace to your package controllers namespace.
    protected $namespace = 'vendor\package\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->mapRoutes($this->app->router);
    }

    protected function mapRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function($router) {
            require (__DIR__ . '/../Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
}
```

Of course, then you need to register this provider in your Laravel config `app.php` file in order to work.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) But you miss '$this->app->router'. I edited your answer. Thanks again.